# Unknown Password

Tags: password

In the seccion of my account password. I put account disabled . And now my laptop ask me for a password to upgrade. But the password i used is not the same. Says it is incorrect. What is the password if the account is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Account disabled means account disabled. No password is valid for a disabled account. You can however reset it to re-activate it. [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)